# How to recover from bad Subversion history?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Using TortoiseSVN 1.9.5, I

1. Made some changes to my working copy, which was HEAD from trunk
2. Branch -> From Working copy, Create intermediate folders, and Switch working copy to a new branch
3. Never touched trunk after 2.
4. Made many revisions in the new branch

Once I was happy with the branch, I switched back to trunk and tried to merge the branch into trunk.  I got a ton of conflicts and tree conflicts, which was very confusing since I had made no changes to trunk.

After looking through the two different branches' histories/logs, I discovered that the branch thinks it branched from trunk at rev916 instead of the actual rev938.  Not only is that not true, the branch has all the revisions from trunk up to rev938 (and I have done no merging).  Also, looking through the repo's db/revs/939 (first commit of branch), I can see many references to 938 and a couple references to 916.

I tried several combinations of changing a couple of the 916s to 938s in the db/revs/939, but that didn't seem to help in the working copy or repo browser's history.

How do I fix the repo?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you commit your changes in the trunk before creating the branch from the working copy? Did your sync your branch with the trunk before trying to reintegrate the branch?

Comment: No, but I've had no issue with TortoiseSVN correctly branching from working copy in the past with changes, which I've done many times without incident.  Yes, even though there weren't any changes to trunk.